# No write permissions when trying to install gem in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: rubygems, ubuntu-12.04, sqlite3-ruby

I am trying to run this command

```
gem intstall sqlite3-ruby -v 1.2.5
```

on Ubuntu 12.04 but I keep getting this error:

> you dont have write permissions into the /var/lib/gems/1.9.1 directory

This is stopping me from running the bundle install command completely and therefore I can't run the rails server command.

Answer (score 2):

Try it with sudo privileges:

```
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby
```

---

If you run into

> /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)

ensure you also have `ruby1.9.1-dev` installed.

To install it, run this command

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

Comment: Thank you so much - this has fixed things for me - much apprcieated

Comment: Please [mark the answer as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) if necessary. Thanks.